# Deliver message to only one queue bound to a routing key in RabbiqMQ Direct exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ and this is confusing me. I have setup a direct exchange and different queues subscribe to different routing keys on this exchange. What I want is that if a message gets published with one routing key, it gets consumed from one subscriber only, no matter how many queues subscribe to that routing key.

Current scenario:

Exchange (type: direct)

```
-QueueA1  (receives message A from exchange with routing key of "TypeA")
-QueueA2  (also receive message A from exchange with routing key of "TypeA")
-QueueB  (doesn't receive message A because it subscribes to key "TypeB")
```

Desired:

```
-QueueA1  (receives message A from exchange with routing key of "TypeA")
-QueueA2  (doesn't receive message A because it's already consumed by QueueA1)
-QueueB  (doesn't receive message A because it subscribes to key "TypeB")
```

Do I need to use a different exchange? How do I achieve desired scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using a single `QueueA` with multiple consumers subscribed to this queue:

```
Direct exchange
|
|-- ["TypeA"]--> QueueA
|                |-- Consumer A1
|                `-- Consumer A2
|
`-- ["TypeB"]--> QueueB
```

In this case, a message queued on `QueueA` will be delivered to only one consumer. The consumer which gets the message is undefined however: they are picked in a round-robin manner.

Answer (score 0):

w/ RabbitMQ, all routing keys that match within a given exchange, will have  a copy of the message delivered to the specified queue.

So, in your scenario, you will always have QueueA1 and QueueA2 receive messages of TypeA. This is how routing keys work. There is no way around this, using a single exchange.

If you need QueueA1 and QueueA2 to receive different messages, then you either:

- need to use different routing keys to bind the queue, or
- need to use a different exchange

Regarding the suggestion from Jean-Sebastient...

This scenario will allow either Consumer A1 *or* Consumer A2 to handle the message in question, but does so by having them both subscribe to the same queue.

If you're trying to ensure there is one 1 consumer that receives the message, then this is what you want to do. But, if you need both queues and need to ensure only one queue receives the message, then you need to go with one of the other options I suggested.

Finally, if you are looking at guaranteeing a message is processed only once, none of these options will do that.

On the surface, it will look like this works most of the time. But there will be scenarios where something goes wrong and you'll have more than one queue or consumer process the same message.

To handle this scenario, you need to look a "idempotence" in your message handling. This is most commonly handled with a database and an ID to say it has been processed already, but there are other solutions out there.